# splunk admin password

Tags: splunk

How do I reset splunk admin password?
I guess I need access to the file system that Splunk is running on in order to modify the password file.
It does not use database so do I need to change a file/ variable?

Comment: How is this POSSIBLY off topic?  This is spot on.

Answer (score 8):

If you forgot your admin password you will need access to the file system that Splunk is running on in order to modify the password file. To reset the admin password:

- Move the $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/passwd file to $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/passwd.bak
- Restart Splunk. After the restart you should be able to login using the default login (admin/changeme).

If you created other user accounts, copy those entries from the backup file into the new passwd file and restart splunk.