# change splunk admin password from linux cli

Tags: splunk

How do I reset splunk admin password? I guess I need access to the file system that Splunk is running on in order to modify the password file.
The solution from here does not work somehow: [splunk admin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088201/splunk-admin-password)

Answer (score 1):

The other solution won't work for Splunk version 7.1 and above, due to changes in the way passwords and accounts are managed.

In order to change a forgotten admin password, I have found the easiest method is to perform the following.

- Run `/opt/splunk/bom/splunk hash-passwd 'MySecureP@55word'` and save the output
- Note that the password needs to meet password complexity requirements, so use something complex
- Stop Splunk
- Edit the password file, `vim /opt/splunk/etc/passwd`
- Replace the hash after the admin user with the output you saved from the hash-passwd function
- Save the file, and restart Splunk
- You should now be able to login with the new credentials.

For example, something like the following, you would put your saved hash between `:admin:` and `::Administrator:`.

`:admin:$6$askdjlakjklj434j2l3jrlkj3l4j23j4l23kj4l23j4l23jljlj5l34jl5kjljasdkljl/bjkhjGHGhjGc679hIJj87asda0lasdbJK::Administrator:admin:changeme@example.com:::12345`

Answer (score -1):

Have another user with the admin role sign in and change the password for user 'admin'.